# django, entity framework, and dumping data

Tags: django, entity-framework

In django, there are built-in commands dumpdata and loaddata that export data from the database into a json format and load it back in, respectively. This is nifty for testing purposes, unless your schema is a moving target. Then something like factory boy is a better idea. Come to think of it, a plugin for dumpdata that outputs factory boy calls would be pretty sweet..

Is there any equivalent tool for entity framework? NdbUnit is a thing, but it suffers the same drawbacks as django's fixtures, so I guess you'd want something that outputs object literals and appropriate EF bookkeeping.